# Bought VLC UWP Unity plugin for playing rtsp stream, It works in edtior but cannot receive from internet

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, vlc, rtsp

I have already enabled InternetClient, InternetClientServer and PrivateInternetClientServer. The UWP app only receives local stream on the development PC, it cannot play source from internet. Any cue?

The log from native lib not saved in log file, don't know why:

VLCPlayerExample Open http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4
VLCPlayerExample Openhttp://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4
VLCPlayerExample Play
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
http Debug:
http Error:
http Error:
oldhttp Debug:
oldhttp Debug:
oldhttp Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Error:
oldhttp Error:
main Debug:
main Error:
main Error:

The log for local working rtsp did not have any error:
VLCPlayerExample Open rtsp://localhost:8554/
VLCPlayerExample Openrtsp://localhost:8554/
VLCPlayerExample Play
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
live555 Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
live555 Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
live555 Debug:
main Debug:
live555 Debug:
live555 Debug:
live555 Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
h264 Debug:
h264 Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
avcodec Debug:
avcodec Debug:
avcodec Debug:
avcodec Debug:
avcodec Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
faad Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
lua Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
faad Warning:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:
main Debug:

Test the example scene inside Unity it works very well. Desktop app also works fine. Only UWP app cannot received stream from internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it should be set inside Visual Studio, not Unity. Can close already.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RUWk.png)